# Elimination of trigonometric functions

Tags: equation-solving, trigonometry

I want to eliminate $\gamma$ from the system of equations given below:

```
{ϵ^2 (a μ - (FF Sin[γ])/ωn0) == 0, 
 (a^2 ϵ κ1)/(8 ωn0) + ϵ^2 (σ + (a^4 K)/(32 ωn0) + (FF Cos[γ])/(a ωn0)) == 0}
```

Comment: Solve the first equation for `Sin[Gamma]` and the second for `Cos[Gamma]`, then set `Sin[Gamma]^2+Cos[Gamma]^2==1`.

Comment: You can let Mathematica solve it for you, `Eliminate[ eqns, γ]`.

Comment: When `Eliminate` falls short, add the standard trig identity and use `GroebnerBasis` e.g. `First[GroebnerBasis[{\[Epsilon]^2 (a \[Mu] - (FF Sin[\[Gamma]])/\
\[Omega]n0), (a^2 \[Epsilon] \[Kappa]1)/(8 \[Omega]n0) + \[Epsilon]^2 \
(\[Sigma] + (a^4 K)/(32 \[Omega]n0) + (FF Cos[\[Gamma]])/(a \
\[Omega]n0)), Cos[\[Gamma]]^2 + Sin[\[Gamma]]^2 - 1}, {Cos[\[Gamma]], 
   Sin[\[Gamma]]}]]` or a variant thereof

Comment: Thanks. Also I succeeded by using TrigToExp and then replace Exp[x] by a variable y and then eliminate y. Thanks